# Move all files and folders except folders with the name .foo

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have folder structure, where some of the subfolders have a .foo subfolder inside. I want to move the root folder structure from foldera to folderb. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to do, maybe provide an example of what you would like.

Comment: What should happen with the .foo folders when the rest is being moved?

Comment: The .foo folders can either be removed or left alone. It doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove the .foo folders then it's simple... simply delete them and then move the whole thing:

```
find foldera -type d -name .foo -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
mv foldera folderb
```

If you want to keep the .foo folders then you can move the whole thing and then move only the .foo folders back:

```
mv foldera folderb
cd folderb
find -type d -name .foo -exec mkdir ../foldera/'{}' -p \;
find -type d -name .foo -exec mv '{}' ../foldera/'{}' \;
```

Hope this helps.